# Cut and Awk command : Delimiter behaviour

Tags: linux, awk

I tried to use cut command to get a list of file names and their sizes from "ls -l" command output.

```
$ ls -l | cut -f 5,9 -d " "
```

It gives me output based on 'SINGLE WHITE SPACE' as a delimiter. When "ls -l" output contains consecutive spaces in certain rows, then the output of the command is not proper for those rows. 
 The rows which have only single white space as column separator, give correct output.

When I run following command:

```
$ ls -l | awk '{ print $5"\t"$9 }'
```

awk is ignoring multiple spaces and properly extracting columns from "ls -l" output.
While, cut is treating each space as a delimiter, there by putting values in wrong columns.

It gives correct output for all rows.

Why is this happening ? What can I do to work this out with cut command ?

Comment: Got it. Difference is because AWK can split using multiple characters as delimeters. Whereas CUT can split using single character as delimiter only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

awk splits fields on whitespace. cut splits fields on a delimiting *character*. awk is the better tool for this problem.

As an alternative, you can pipe `ls -l` into a utility that either compresses multiple space chars (maybe `tr -s`), or into a utility that replaces multiple space chars with a single one (maybe `sed`). *Then* cut will do what you want it to.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- your code will not print the full filename if it contains spaces.  To get the file size and name, use [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat):

```
stat -c "%s %n" *
```

Comment: Thanks @Glen. Links in your concise answer are really informative.

Answer (score 3):

try this?:

```
ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5, 9
```

Comment: Will it not remove all occurrences of ' '?

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know.